# Autohotkey. Как сделать поиск по координатам относительно рабочего стола?

Tags: autohotkey

Написал простенький скрипт

```
#Persistent
Loop
    {
        ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 982, 233, 1421, 530, *104, test.png

        if ErrorLevel = 1
        {
            SoundPlay, ding.wav
            MsgBox, , Attention!, Visitor!
            IfMsgBox, OK, Reload
        }
    
    }
```

Имеется два монитора: 1 - рабочий, 2 - изображение с камер. Суть скрипта в том, что он мониторит изображение с камеры и в случае попадания в поле зрения какого-либо объекта, которого там не было - срабатывает звуковой сигнал, вылетает окошко с оповещением и после нажатия на ОК скрипт возвращается в начало. В моем случае это сделано для того, чтобы система реагировала на человека. Скрипт работает исправно, однако работает он только если не открывать других окон, так как координаты он начинает считать относительно активного окна. Я погуглил и нашел Coordmode. Добавив строчки, скрипт успешно запускается, но не работает как нужно. Он всегда будто находит картинку, даже если в поле зрения камеры появится объект. Если убрать Coordmode и запустить скрипт с рабочего стола - все работает исправно. Подскажите, что не так:

```
#Persistent
Loop
    {
CoordMode Pixel        
ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 982, 233, 1421, 530, 1920, 1080, *104, test.png

        if ErrorLevel = 1
        {
            SoundPlay, ding.wav
            MsgBox, , Attention!, Visitor!
            IfMsgBox, OK, Reload
        }

    }
```

как сделать, чтобы координаты считались всегда относительно рабочего стола, даже если запущено другое окно? Размер рабочей зоны обоих мониторов 3839х1079